# Limiting Records returned from SpineJS fetch()

Tags: javascript, spine.js

I'd like to have some routes in an app I'm writing which limit the number of results returned.

Currently I have the following in my main controller:

```
init: function(){

    MyModel.bind("refresh", this.proxy(this.addAll));

    this.routes({
        "/subset": function(){
            var items = MyModel.select(function(model){
                //Do a test on model
                return (itemToBeReturned === true);
            });
        }
    });
    MyModel.fetch();
},

addAll: function () {
    MyModel.each(this.proxy(this.addOne));
},

addOne: function (model){
   //Do some stuff with model
}
```

I want to define a number of routes which fetch subsets of the original data. As you can see I'm not doing anything with the results I'm filtering within my route at the moment.

Is there a way of causing fetch() to only return a subset of all records so that the refresh event only receives those records as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to respond with what I think is the right answer here after musing over it the last couple of nights and drawing my own conclusions. Hopefully it may help someone.

The question really boils down to whether it is appropriate to be doing this filtering on the data before it hits the refresh method. The fetch is hitting a server and refresh receives those records - that's not going to change unless you start playing with the internals of spine.

I'm basically asking how to filter the data client side. What might be better is to request only the subset of the data through a subset URL and then not having to worry about how to reduce down to ***only*** the data I need. In fact, this is probably the most sensible approach given that the only other way of doing this (that I can see right now) is by letting a default fetch occur, and then hiding all those records that don't appear in my data subset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically doing a similar thing. Here's what works (that I've seen):

```
Model.extend({
    url: '/api/model', //whatever your endpoint is
    filter: function(id) {  //pass in whatever you want it to match
        return this.select(function(c) { //c is the record it is checking
            return c.id === id; //returns true and displays the record
        });
    }
});

var filteredItems = Model.filter(id); //filteredItems is a subset of the records.
Controller.render(filteredItems); //pass them to your render function, or do whatever you want with them.
```